# Any one know how to run gradle 3.2.1 on android studio 4.2.2?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

me have a project with Gradle 3.2.1, but my android studio 4.2.2. not working run my project. anyone have the same experience as me?

Comment: Please share the error output you encounter

Comment: Why are you not upgrading gradle? Upgrade your gradle version and it will work fine.

Comment: cause that project already big apps with modular, it error gradle when update to new version

Comment: @penadidik Then you have to chose: Use an old Android Studio version or upgrade your project and fix the errors to work with a recent version of Android Studio.